# Python: Finding a minimum value according to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, a-star

So this is what I'd "like" to be able to write:

```
cur_loc = min(open_set,key=lambda x:costs[x])
```

`cur_loc` is a tuple, and the goal is to set it equal to the tuple in `open_set` with the lowest cost. (and you find the cost of `x` with `costs[x]`)

How could I do this? I tried Python.org's documentation on `min()`, but I didn't seem to find much help.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I resolved my own problem.

I was retarded and hadn't initialized the costs dictionary. I was actually copy and pasting someone else's python code in order to test what they were doing, but apparently the snippet they created didn't include the initialization part. Woops. If anyone is interested:

```
        for row in range(self.rows):
            for col in range(self.cols):
                myloc = (row,col)
                if (myloc) not in closed_set:

                    costs[myloc] = (abs(end_row-row)+abs(end_col - col))*10

                    if (myloc) not in open_set:
                        open_set.add(myloc)

                    parents[myloc] = cur_loc

        cur_loc = min(open_set,key=lambda x:costs[x])
```

Comment: You'll need to provide an example of `open_set` and the related `costs` dictionary.  Also.  Why are these separated from each other?  Is `open_set` some subset of items in `costs`?  Is it a proper `set` instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Worked for me.  What's your question?

```
>>> costs = { '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3 }
>>> open_set = set( ['1','2'] )
>>> min(open_set,key=lambda x:costs[x])
'1'
```

Comment: The OP specified that *open_set* consisted of tuples and this exact code did not work for him, so the problem is likely that the cost dictionary lookup does not accept a tuple as a key.  IOW, this response don't seem like a real answer.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger: "The OP specified that open_set consisted of tuples "?  Really?  How did I miss that?  Can you provide the exact quote from the question so people can downvote me appropriately?

Comment: "... the goal is to set it equal to **the tuple in** `open_set` ..."

Comment: @Ben: That may explain why my comment on the question was a request for examples of `open_set`.  Thanks for that.  Lacking an example, I figured I would indicate that -- generally -- the approach might work.  However, lacking details, what can we do?

Answer (score 3):

The you supplied would be correct if `cost[x]` was a dictionary lookup with tuples as keys.  I think you may have meant to extract a field for the tuple and lookup the cost of that field:

```
>>> costs = dict(red=10, green=20, blue=30)
>>> open_set = {('red', 'car'), ('green', 'boat'), ('blue', 'plane')}
>>> min(open_set, key=lambda x: costs[x[0]])
('red', 'car')
```